# Getting distinct values with the highest value in a specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

How can I get the highlighted rows from the table below in SQL? (Distinct rows based on User name with the highest Version  are highlighted)

[image]

In case you need plain text table:

```
+----+-----------+---+
| 1  | John      | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 2  | Brad      | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 3  | Brad      | 3 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 4  | Brad      | 2 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 5  | Jenny     | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 6  | Jenny     | 2 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 7  | Nick      | 4 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 8  | Nick      | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 9  | Nick      | 3 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 10 | Nick      | 2 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 11 | Chris     | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 12 | Nicole    | 2 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 13 | Nicole    | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 14 | James     | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 15 | Christine | 1 |
+----+-----------+---+
```

What I have so far is (works for one user)

```
SELECT USER, VERSION 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE USER = 'Brad' 
AND VERSION  = (SELECT MAX(VERSION ) FROM TABLE WHERE USER= 'Brad')
```

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: I don't. I meant Oracle SQL syntax by PL/SQL

Comment: PL/SQL is exclusively for stored procedures and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might help you :

```
select id, user, version 
from 
(
   select id, user, version, row_number() over (partition by user order by version desc) rownum
   from yourtable
) as t
where t.rownum = 1
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a060/6)

Comment: All 3 answers work. Chose this one as answer because it's the first one

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT USER, max(VERSION) VERSION
FROM TABLE GROUP BY USER;
```

If you need an ID then

```
SELECT ID, USER, VERSION FROM (
    SELECT ID, USER, VERSION, 
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY VERSION DESC) RNK 
    FROM TABLE
) WHERE RNK = 1;
```

if you have

```
| 2  | Brad      | 5 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 3  | Brad      | 3 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 4  | Brad      | 5 |
```

The query with RANK gives you both users

```
| 2  | Brad      | 5 |
+----+-----------+---+
| 4  | Brad      | 5 |
```

If you need only one row then replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()`

In your query you're using `AND VERSION  = (SELECT MAX(VERSION ) FROM TABLE WHERE USER= 'Brad')` which is equivalent to RANK() (all rows with the max VERSION)

Comment: And what about the id?

Answer (score 2):

The [`first_value`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm) analytic function should do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE (id) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY version DESC)
       name,
       FIRST_VALUE (version) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY version DESC)
FROM   my_table
```

Another way to go would be to use the [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#i86310) function:

```
SELECT id, name, version
FROM   (SELECT id, name, version
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY version DESC) rn
        FROM   my_table)
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Not sure which I prefer, personally. They each have their merit and their ugliness.